# Window snapping by hotkey with icewm?

Tags: hotkeys, icewm

Is it possible to assign the <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>  hotkeys for snapping windows to half the screen?

### Motivation

Under Windows 7 and newer, pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> causes the active window to fill half of the screen. The same behavior exists under various Linux window managers, or at least can be easily configured, e.g. through KDE's `systemsettings5`.

In home-office access my Work-PC is using `icewm` as window manager for better remote performance. In the documentation, I couldn't find anything about snapping hotkeys, only about setting global hotkeys through `$HOME/.icewm/keys`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your keys file you can define:

```
key "Alt+Left" icesh -f left top sizeto 50% 100%

key "Alt+Right" icesh -f right top sizeto 50% 100%
```

Check the [icesh man page](https://ice-wm.org/man/icesh.html) to see if your installed version
supports these `icesh` options.

Comment: Out system admins have installed 1.4.2, where much of this is not yet available. Will have to ask about it, maybe newer versions made problems with X2Go. But icesh is definitely the right solution here.

Comment: X2Go supports all versions of icewm equally well. They have optimized icewm to eliminate most expose events and reduce drawing operations. This would benefit networked access.